# Removing django default permissions from auth models

Tags: python, django, migration

guys im trying to remove default django permissions i'll never use in my project but with no success. When I make migration it states that migration is made with success but there's no effect, like it skipped the function. I'm pretty sure code is ok because i tested it in shell. Any ideas?
Here's code for migration:

```
from django.db import migrations


def remove_redundant_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth.Permission')
    app_labels = ['admin', 'reversion', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'sites']
    Permission.objects.filter(content_type__app_label__in=app_labels).delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('users', '0014_auto_20160808_0738'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(remove_redundant_permissions),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's permessions are generated with `post_migrate` signal. This means even if you delete them in migration they will be regenerated after migration completes.

Here is code from django

```
# django/contrib/auth/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth.checks import check_user_model
from django.core import checks
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .management import create_permissions


class AuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'django.contrib.auth'
    verbose_name = _("Authentication and Authorization")

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(create_permissions,
            dispatch_uid="django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions")
        checks.register(check_user_model, checks.Tags.models)
```

As you see `auth` app has this `AppConfig` which regenerates permissions with `create_permissions` function.

Why do you want to delete default django permissions? Do they block you from doing something?

Comment: just cosmetic reasons, thank you that answers my question, i guess i ll let them be then.